# How to stop exception propagation if jms broker is down when sending a message with spring integration?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I configured spring xml based interceptor, which sends a jms message to activemq queue on each invokation of some transactional method after it is commited. It's happening with the following xml code.

```
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="filteredStakesChannel" destination="stakesQueue" delivery-persistent="true" explicit-qos-enabled="true" />
```

But if the activemq server is down i get connection refused exception, which is propagated and i don't want this to happen even if the jms delivery fails. Is this possible? 
Should i use some error-channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make fileredStakesChannel an Executor channel and the send will run on a different thread.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel

Use the <task/> namespace to define an executor to use.